# give different width to different td in table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a web app in which I want a table with multiple `<tr>` and `<td>`

here is my code

```
<tr>
  <th style="width:30px;">date</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>10-10-2016</td>
</tr>
```

it worked fine until I add another tr

```
<tr>
   <td style="width:200px;">Expense incurred towards sessions</td>
</tr>
```

It is increasing the width of my date(th,td) or else it is showing me other td like

> Expense
>
> incurred
>
> towards
>
> sessions

I don't want to increase the width of my date td but want my second td to be on the same line

> Expense incurred towards sessions

like this how I need to css this

This is my table

```
<table id="table" ng-hide="hidetable" class="table font" style="width:100%;
 margin-top:30px; padding-top:10px;">
```

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this resemble anything you're after? [Here is more](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_colspan.asp) on the `colspan=" "` attribute used to achieve this.

```html
<table id="table" ng-hide="hidetable" class="table font" style="width:100%;
 margin-top:30px; padding-top:10px;">
<tr>
  <th style="width:30px;background-color:#f2f2f2;">date</th>
  <td style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">10-10-2016</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">Expense incurred towards sessions</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:30px;">date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>10-10-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">Expense incurred towards sessions</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```